# Android: keyboard hide the edittext

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, keyboard, android-scrollview

I know it's a common discussion, but I've tried ALL the things I can find on internet, without solution.
Here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#eeeeee">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/logo" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:text="@string/info_trasloco"
            android:background="@drawable/bordo_sotto_titolo"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:id="@+id/cliente_logo" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cliente_logo"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/smontaggio"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/trasferimento"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/smontaggio" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/trasferimento"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/rimontaggio"
                android:id="@+id/trasferimento" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rimontaggio"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra_info"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/rimontaggio" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_spostata"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_1"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra_info_txt"
                android:id="@+id/extra_info" />
            <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/ingresso_ok"
                android:id="@+id/extra_info_txt" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:text="@string/dichi"
            android:background="@drawable/bordo_sotto_titolo"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/testo_dichi"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_spostata" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/testo_dichi"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ingresso"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/cucina"
                android:id="@+id/ingresso_ok" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cucina"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/tinello"
                android:id="@+id/cucina" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tinello"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/sala"
                android:id="@+id/tinello" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_2"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sala"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/salotto"
                android:id="@+id/sala" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/salotto"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/studio"
                android:id="@+id/salotto" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/studio"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/camera_matrimoniale"
                android:id="@+id/studio" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_4"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_3"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/camera_matrimoniale"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/cameretta"
                android:id="@+id/camera_matrimoniale" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cameretta"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/cameretta_2"
                android:id="@+id/cameretta" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cameretta_2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/cameretta_3"
                android:id="@+id/cameretta_2" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_5"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_4"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cameretta_3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/cameretta_4"
                android:id="@+id/cameretta_3" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cameretta_4"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/cameretta_5"
                android:id="@+id/cameretta_4" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cameretta_5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/bagno"
                android:id="@+id/cameretta_5" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_5_1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_5"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bagno"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/bagno_2"
                android:id="@+id/bagno" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bagno_2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/corridoio_zona_notte"
                android:id="@+id/bagno_2" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/corridoio_zona_notte"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/ripostiglio"
                android:id="@+id/corridoio_zona_notte" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_5_2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_5_1"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ripostiglio"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/garage"
                android:id="@+id/ripostiglio" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/garage"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/cantina"
                android:id="@+id/garage" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cantina"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/taverna"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/cantina" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_5_3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_5_2"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/taverna"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/mansarda"
                android:id="@+id/taverna" />
            <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mansarda"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra1"
                android:id="@+id/mansarda" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="21)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra1_txt"
                    android:id="@+id/extra1" />
                <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra2"
                    android:id="@+id/extra1_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>






        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_5_3_1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_5_3"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="22)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra2_txt"
                    android:id="@+id/extra2" />
                <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra3"
                    android:id="@+id/extra2_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="23)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra3_txt"
                    android:id="@+id/extra3" />
                <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra4"
                    android:id="@+id/extra3_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="24)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra4_txt"
                    android:id="@+id/extra4" />
                <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra5"
                    android:id="@+id/extra4_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_5_3_2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_5_3_1"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="25)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra5_txt"
                    android:id="@+id/extra5" />
                <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra6"
                    android:id="@+id/extra5_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="26)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra6_txt"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:id="@+id/extra6" />
                <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra7"
                    android:id="@+id/extra6_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="27)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra7_txt"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:id="@+id/extra7" />
                <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra8"
                    android:id="@+id/extra7_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_2_5_3_3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_5_3_2"
            android:weightSum="1.2">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <CheckBox android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="28)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/extra8_txt"
                    android:id="@+id/extra8" />
                <EditText android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/dettagli"
                    android:id="@+id/extra8_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>






        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:text="@string/dettaglio_costi"
            android:background="@drawable/bordo_sotto_titolo"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_2_5_3_3"
            android:id="@+id/cliente_logo_2" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fase_3_1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cliente_logo_2"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <EditText android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                android:minLines="10"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/costo_dettagli"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/dettagli"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/fase_3_2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fase_3_1"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/costo"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
            <EditText android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:id="@+id/costo_dettagli"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need that the `android:id="@+id/dettagli"` is FULLY VISIBLE when touched (and putted out the keyboard)... for now, it just show the first line and edit the text it's very complicated.

I've tried all in the manifest, for now it's a

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: fully visible means please can you be bit more clear

Comment: ? i mean that i must see the entire edittext.... now the keyboard goes above

Comment: may be this idea can work when you click one the edittext make it full   screen :)

Comment: and how can i? but it's only an arrangment... not a coding solution

Comment: let me check your layout first

Comment: can you share your string file also

Comment: no, because you don't need it. replace it with aaaaaa

Comment: you have to make gravity center_vertical& left or it will not work

Comment: to what, to the edittext or to the whole view?

Comment: just edittext gravity

Comment: the problem remains.
it's linked with android:gravity="top" because this command put the blinking cursor at the first line, and the keyboard is directly after that!

Answer (score 1):

add this to the edit text field in your layout android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

Comment: i already have android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan".
i've tried your idea, but it makes the whole case more ugly

Comment: see this second topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884882/android-multiline-edittext-and-keyboard-problems

Comment: it's pasted in this topic, the whole xml :-|

Comment: i tried the layout part you provided in the second post and it works fine, maybe the keyboard needs some space to expand and the part in which it resides Should Not Be Scrollable

Comment: try making a new project and just place the code you provided in the second post in project's layout and drag the edit text field to the bottom of layout and then click on the text field and it works fine